# Which language is this? (written in 1985)

Tags: refactoring

```
 PROGRAM KIR
 DIMENSION ACL(4,100)
 BYTE NAM(16)
 REAL *8, W
 COMMON/MOD/ACL,N,NL,NU
 FORMAT(16A1)
 TYPE *, 'DOCUMENT NAME'
 ACCEPT 100, NAM
 CALL ASSIGN(1,NAM)
 FORMAT(I2, 213)
```

I couldn't recognize this language using keywords like TYPE, ACCEPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like FORTRAN 77 to me. The statements seem to match.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/index.html